# error cannot find symbol when trying to complie

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d

I am trying to follow as many tutorials online as possible for Java, but I am angry because nearly every one of them coughs up an error of some kind. In this example, I have found a program that creates a basic gui to contain the java2d graphics and informs you where to insert the functions. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// Swing Program Template
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwingTemplateJPanel extends JPanel {
   // Name-constants
   public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
   public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;
   public static final String TITLE = "...Title...";
   // ......

   // private variables of GUI components
   // ......

   /** Constructor to setup the GUI components */
   public SwingTemplateJPanel() {
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
      // "this" JPanel container sets layout
      // setLayout(new ....Layout());

      // Allocate the UI components
      // .....

      // "this" JPanel adds components
      // add(....)

      // Source object adds listener
      // .....
  }

   /** Custom painting codes on this JPanel */
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);  // paint background
      setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);

      // Your custom painting codes
      // ......
   }

   /** The entry main() method */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Run GUI codes in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread safety
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
            frame.setContentPane(new SwingTemplateJPanel());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();             // "this" JFrame packs its components
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center the application window
            frame.setVisible(true);            // show it
         }
      });
   }
}
```

After adding drawLine(1,2,3,4) in the place I assume is approriate, it returns  error: cannot find symbol when trying to compile, the only thing I need is a simple gui where I can statically plot each pixel on, plz help.

Comment: I believe you mean to do:  `g.drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);` where `g` is the `Graphics` object you're passing in.

Comment: You didn't ask for this, but I'm going to throw it in because I think you may not know to ask it.  You appear to have a rudimentary understanding of java, and are trying to learn more about it, that's great.  However, trying to do it in the world of Swing UIs with paintComponent methods, etc., seem to me to be too big a piece to take on at one time.  UIs in general have many complexities that are that much harder when you don't have the language basics down.  You need to have classes, objects, methods, scope, syntax, etc. down cold first.

Answer (score 3):

[`drawLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) is an instance method of `java.awt.Graphics` not `JPanel` or any of its super classes

```
g.drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);
```